# Creating a printable image when using jQuery freezeframe

Tags: jquery, html, css

The Freezeframe plugin by Chris Antonellis allows you to animate a gif upon mouseover by using the command:

```
< img src="image.gif" freezeframe />
```

See an example on his website [here](http://freezeframe.chrisantonellis.com/) and also see the documentation [here](http://freezeframe.chrisantonellis.com/documentation/).

Unfortunately, when this plugin is used, the print version of the website fails to display the image (when an animated gif is embedded on the site, usually a static version pops up on printed pages). Is there a way we can fix it so that it prints properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set specific styles for the print version of the website using media types.

```
@media print {
    /* CSS styles here will only affect the website when it is printed. */
}
```

When you print an animated gif it will only display the first frame of the animation. If you'd like to create a separate 'snapshot' image of the animated gif to allow for more control over what will be seen on the printed version you can embed another image on the page.

For your specific needs, it'd probably be best to wrap each of the images in a `div` with specific CSS applied based on the media type. The following code will allow you to have an animated gif display for regular visitors on your website and allow for you to specify a separate image to display for the printed version.

```
<style>
.print-image {
  display:none;
}

@media print {
    .screen-image {
        display:none;
     }
      .print-image {
        display:block;
      }
}
</style>

<!-- Content within the .screen-image element will be displayed to normal visitors -->
<div class="screen-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x250" />
    <p>Image for normal viewing.</p>
</div>

<!-- Content within the .print-image element will be displayed when website is printed -->
<div class="print-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x250" />
    <p>Image for print view.</p>
</div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/gU57Y/ - test it out by pressing CTRL+P and testing the print view.

If you're curious to learn more about applying styles based on media types - you can learn more about it on the [media types page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) at [W3.org](http://W3.org).

Comment: thank you for your help. I've tested this with normal images, and it works very well. However, with the freezeframe plugin, the print version indeed hides the visibility of the image, but the blank space for the image still appears. The freezeframe example seems to break your suggestion. I have a minimal example [here](http://www.theshapeofmath.com/playground).

Comment: @TSGM I've modified my original answer. This should do the trick!